# cannot read URL variable in SQL query

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a simple problem with my node js application.
Is that : I can't read or use an URL variable in a request query , I think it said that that the ' req.params ' cannot be applicated to a unknown variable.

**The error is :**

> Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

**This is my server side :**

```
app.get('/Home/:pwd', function (req,res){
    var sess;
    sess  = req.session;
    //var PWD = req.params("pwd");
    var DAO = require('./lib/DAO')

    DAO.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name = '.req.params("pwd"), function(Value) {
        res.render ( 'Home', {data : Value} )
    });

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //pour un affichage json

});
```

**And this is my ejs file :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

{
"name": <%=data[0].id%>,
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node app"
}

</body>
</html>
```

Thank guys for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think need to change to

```
'SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name = '  + req.params("pwd")
```

FROM

```
'SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name = '.req.params("pwd")
```

A plain string has no property req, hence .params will be of no parent.